# Organizing Meteor with client and server directories

Tags: meteor

I am starting out on Meteor, I've got everything running from one coffee file, but I would like to get organized and move some code to /public and /server. But, when I do this, my collection is undefined. I've moved around a lot of code, but the collection stays undefined. I've removed the autopublish and insecure packages. What am I doing wrong?

/main.coffee

```
Trips = new Meteor.Collection "trips"

if Meteor.isClient
    Meteor.subscribe 'trips'

if Meteor.isServer
    Meteor.publish 'trips', -> Trips.find()

    Trips.allow
        insert: -> true
        update: -> true
        remove: -> true
```

/client/trips.coffee

```
Meteor.startup ->
    Template.Trips.all_trips = -> Trips.find()
```

Comment: I recommend you also leverage local smart packages (under packages/) ASAP. They are very flexible in terms of controlling load order and where (server/client) files go

Comment: Do you mean add existing packages to use in my project or write my own and use them as a storage place for the app logic?

Comment: Write your own. Anything that feels like it could be reusable logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `Trips` to be accessible to the other files, [Meteor 0.6.0 introduced variable scoping](http://www.meteor.com/blog/2013/04/04/meteor-060-brand-new-distribution-system-app-packages-npm-integration) you have a `Trips` defined in your root directory so its not global & your `client/trips.coffee` cant see it. You could make it global with an `@`:

In your `/main.coffee`

```
@Trips = new Meteor.Collection "trips"
```

So this would be accessible to other files (both client and server).

When you split up your file further you should end up with 3 files:

**/main.coffee** (Accessible by both server and client and loaded first)

```
@Trips = new Meteor.Collection "trips"
```

**/client/trips.coffee**

```
Meteor.subscribe 'trips'
Meteor.startup ->
    Template.Trips.all_trips = -> Trips.find()
```

**/server/server.coffee**

```
Meteor.publish 'trips', -> Trips.find()

Trips.allow
    insert: -> true
    update: -> true
    remove: -> true
```

Comment: Note that this behavior will be improved soon (with the work on the [linker branch](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/branches))

Comment: This worked like a charm, only next to adding the @, I had to take the Template.Trips.all_trips var out of Meteor.startup(). Thnx!